# Remove a file in c with arguments and unlink() function

Tags: c, unix, unlink

I've been trying to make a program where I can remove a file with an unlink() function. I should be able to insert an argument (name of the file) and receive it, then removing it. For some reason it tells me the file got removed but does't remove at all. Here's what i got so far. I shouldn't use fopen() and functions like that. The files are created in the path /home/me/TP1/Users where all the "Users" are created. What am I doing wrong? Also, I am developing this in UNIX.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    char user [10];
    char *path = argv[1];
    int result;
    const char *filename = "/home/guima/TP1/Users";
    result = access (filename, F_OK);
    int fd;
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        unlink(argv[1]);
        write(1,"Deleted!\n\n", 35);            
    }    
    else
    {
        write(1,"Error!\n\n",30); 
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the result of unlink.  My guess is that is returning some error.  If it returns a negative number, check `errno`, or user `perror` to print the error message.

Comment: Is that because the file was open when you tried to delete it?

Comment: What is your input value? My guess is that you are inputting only the file name and not the full path. And also it's likely your current directory is not the directory where the file resides. So yes, already check return values of function calls such as `unlink`.

Comment: When you mean input value you mean this? 
        'int remove;' 'remove = unlink(path);'

Comment: By _input value_ kaylum meant the argument you give to the program on the command line.

Comment: @Weather Vane - He was _developing this in UNIX._ Unix does not prohibit deletion of open files.